# Getting error undefined reference

Tags: c, linker

**diceroll.c**

```
/*diceroll.c -- dice roll simulation */  
#include "diceroll.h"  
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h> //for library function rand()  

int roll_count = 0; //external linkage  

static int rollem(int sides) /*private to this file */  
{  
    int roll;  

    roll = rand() % sides + 1;  
    ++roll_count;  

    return roll;  
}  
int roll_n_dice(int dice, int sides){  
    int d;  
    int total =  0;  
    if(sides < 2){  
        printf("Need at least 2 sides.\n");  
        return -2;  
    }  
    if(dice < 1){  
        printf("Need at least 1 dice.\n");  
        return -1;  
    }  
    for(d = 0; d < dice; d++){  
    total += rollem(sides);  
    }  
    return total;  
}
```

**Header file**

```
//diceroll.h  
extern int roll_count;  
extern int roll_n_dice(int dice, int sides);
```

**The main program**

```
/*manydice.c -- multiple dice rolls     */  
/*compile with diceroll.c           */  
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h> //for library funcion srand()  
#include <time.h>   //for time()  
#include "diceroll.h"   //for roll_n_dice and roll_count  

int main(void){  
    int dice, roll;  
    int sides;  

    srand((unsigned int ) time(0)); /*randomized seed*/
    printf("Enter the number of sides per die, 0  to stop.\n");
    while(scanf("%d", &sides) == 1 && sides > 0){
        printf("How many dice ?\n");
        scanf("%d", &dice);

        roll = roll_n_dice(dice, sides);
        printf("You have rolled a %d using %d %d-sided dice.\n", roll,           dice, sides);  
        printf("How many sides ? Enter 0 to stop.\n");
}  
printf("The rollem() funcion was called %d times.\n", roll_count);               //used extern variable
printf("Good Fortune To You!!!\n");  

return 0;  
}
```

Here is I am compiling it with

```
gcc manydice.c diceroll.c
```

but it keep saying undfined reference to roll_count and roll_n_dice

How to fix the undfined reference even though I linking both the
source files.

And I also used 2 times:

```
gcc sourcefile.c -o sourcefile.o -c
```

for manydice and diceroll and compile it using the object code   but still I am getting the same error.

I.e:

```
gcc manydice.c -o manydice.o -c
gcc diceroll.c -o diceroll.o -c
gcc -o myresult manydice.o diceroll.o
```

Comment: `gcc manydice.c diceroll.c` should work.

Comment: no it is not working, it says the same undefined reference

Comment: Not sure why this isn't working.  I'd expect both  symbols to be defined in `diceroll.o`.  You can try running `nm diceroll.o` to verify that they're present.  Are you certain you saved your source changes, and that you're picking up the right versions of the files?

Comment: yes i am sure about the changes , and i compiled the right versions of sorce files.and i tried by running nm diceroll.o and its present.

Comment: Did `nm` show the symbols defined in `diceroll.o` as expected?

Comment: not actually when i run it it shows nothing. just the command executed

Comment: Then there's something seriously wrong with your `.o` file.  You don't have `gcc` aliased do you?

Comment: no i didnt
I also tried by gcc manydice.c diceroll.c

Comment: Here's what I'd do:  (1) `rm diceroll.o` (2) `gcc -c diceroll.c` (3) `nm diceroll.o` and see if the symbol table is still empty.  If it is, your compiler is broken.  Also see what `gcc` resolves to.  Perhaps try giving the full path name when invoking it to make sure you're really running the `gcc` you think you're running.

Comment: yes it shows nothing, and sorry i don't get it about the compiler is broken
because other programs are running successfully

Comment: Thanks, i gave the full path and the changes made in diceroll.c was not saved that causes the undefined reference.

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot more sense.  Note that in my first comment I asked if you were certain you'd saved your source changes, and you said you were sure you had.  Next time double-check please.  Close your editor, then open the file again and make sure the contents are correct.

Comment: Yes you were right.Thanks a lot.Now it works fine.